# how to create sub projects in sonar

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

I have multimodule maven project and I would like to analyze all the modules in the same structure in sonar. Right now iam using maven sonar plugin to trigger analysis. All the modules are analyzed in sonar but each module is creating a new project in sonar.

I would like to have one top level project in sonar and all modules as sub projects in that.How do I achieve this?
any help could be appreciated?

Comment: How does your plugin configuration look like? We set up the Sonar plugin, activated by a dedicated profile, in a department wide "super POM". This creates one project per reactor build that references the super POM as its parent.

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer your question. we have a project structure like this

```
tsc    
     tsc-parent
         pom.xml    
     tsc-module1
         tsc-childmodule1
           pom.xml
         tsc-childmodule2
           pom.xml
         pom.xml      
      tsc-commons
         pom.xml 
pom.xml
```

All modules inherit from tsc-parent

sonar analysis in jenkins:

def mavenParams1 = " " + "${PROFILE} -pl tsc-module1/tsc-childmodule1, tsc-module2/tsc-childmodule2 -am"
def goal = " -X sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=tsca -Dsonar.projectName=tsca " + mavenParams1

Comment: I always get the following exception org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project tsc-module1: Maven session does not declare a top level project